# Unit test in ios, Tab bars

Tags: ios, unit-testing, tabs

So i just started to learning unit testing in IOS and i have few simple tasks to complete.

So basically i have created a Tab bar controller with only two tabs.
How can i test that there indeed only two tabs ?

Also, i have an order: 
The first tab and the second tab
How can i test the order of these tabs following the assertion that "first tab" should be placed first and "second tab" should be placed second ?

I assume that i should start from Tests folder, but for now i have no clue from what to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A tab bar controller in iOS has a `tabbar` property. This tab bar, has an `items` property. You can use these to make sure it has the correct number and in the correct order. *However* this seems like a bad test to me. Don't waste time testing things which are trivial, or components which have already been thoroughly tested (such as Apple's own components).

Comment: yeah, i know that this is useless. But i was given these simple tasks and i don't know how to do them. I haven't found any good tutorials about this